Is there a way to set default values of columns that are NOT NULL in postgres?
In PostgreSQL, when a column is marked as NOT NULL and no value is provided for it during insertion, an error is thrown. However, in MySQL, if no value is provided, the default value is set based on the column's type, such as '' for string values, 0 for integers, 0.00 for floats(scale: 2), etc. It's important to note that even in MySQL, this behavior occurs irrespective of whether a default value is explicitly mentioned.
Example:
ALTER TABLE errors ADD COLUMN user_id INT NOT NULL

In MySQL, it will insert 0 if no value is provided, whereas PostgreSQL will throw an error.
Is there a way or a database setting in PostgreSQL to achieve similar behavior, where default values are automatically set for columns marked as NOT NULL?
I am using TypeORM in nestjs and I don't want to provide default value for each column explicitly like this
@Column('int', { default: 0 })
user_id: number;

EDIT 1: I need something like this: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
EDIT 2: I found how MySQL does it and just need it for postgres or would like to know if it is not possible in postgres. Implicit Default Handling in MYSQL

Postgres DDL example: price DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00

@AdrianMaxwell I am not creating these myself as I am using TypeORM. I want to know if there is some setting on db level that I can use to set default value for all tables without having to set explicitly as it happens in MySQL

So you don't want to set the default value, but you do want a default value. And a NULL is not acceptable when you don't provide a value. To my knowledge the MySQL behavior is the exception, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. behave the same as PostgreSQL. If you want a default, you have to tell the database what that default should be.

Quoting the doc:

If there is no default for a column, then the default is null.

And unfortunately there's no setting that would change this behaviour globally, to a type-specific default of empty-but-not-null value. If that's what you need, you have to add an alter table..alter column..set default each time on db end: demo
ALTER TABLE errors 
  ALTER COLUMN user_id SET DEFAULT 0,
  ALTER COLUMN name SET DEFAULT '',
  ALTER COLUMN salary SET DEFAULT 0.0,
  ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT '-infinity'::timestamptz,
  ALTER COLUMN duration SET DEFAULT '[-infinity,infinity)'::tstzrange;

Or each time in your column options, like you showed
@Column({type:'int', default: 0, nullable: false })
user_id: number;

In both cases, if you don't like typing it all out by hand, you should be able to set up your IDE and/or CI/CD pipelines to add that on the fly.
If you want to add it in bulk, you can iterate over information_schema.columns, spot the ones where is_nullable='NO' and check their column_default. You can loop over that and use dynamic SQL to add your specific empty-but-not-null value as the default. The script can be integrated as a post-step in your migrations, so that when you add new models/tables, they also get processed.
select * 
from information_schema.columns
where is_nullable='NO' 
  and column_default is null
  and table_name='errors';


You have to provide a column default explicitly if you don't want it to be NULL.

You can create an event trigger that fires when a new table is created and sets all the defaults that you need. Something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.set_defaults()
    RETURNS EVENT_TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _row    RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR _row IN
        SELECT pg_class.relname AS table_name
            ,  nspname AS schema_name
            ,  column_name
            ,  data_type
        FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
            JOIN pg_class ON pg_class.oid = pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands.objid
            JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
            JOIN information_schema.columns ON table_schema = nspname
                                            AND table_name = pg_class.relname
        WHERE   command_tag = 'CREATE TABLE'
        AND     is_nullable = 'NO'
        AND     column_default IS NULL
    LOOP
        -- Set default value based on data type
        IF _row.data_type IN ('integer', 'bigint', 'smallint') THEN
            EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I SET DEFAULT 0;'
                , _row.schema_name
                , _row.table_name
                , _row.column_name);
        ELSIF _row.data_type IN('date', 'timestamp without time zone', 'timestamp with time zone') THEN
            EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I SET DEFAULT NOW();'
                , _row.schema_name
                , _row.table_name
                , _row.column_name);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER set_defaults ON ddl_command_end
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.set_defaults();

CREATE TABLE public.foo
(
    id INT       NOT NULL,
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    content text
);

 -- success, using all columns and DEFAULT:
INSERT INTO public.foo(id, ts, content)
VALUES(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'my content')
RETURNING *;

 -- success, only the columns that you need:
INSERT INTO public.foo(content)
VALUES('my content')
RETURNING *;

-- fail, using all columns and NULLs:
INSERT INTO public.foo(id, ts, content)
VALUES(null, null, 'my content')
RETURNING *;

This trigger fires on the ddl_command_end event, when the new table exists and can be altered. Check the data types and default values, to make sure they do what you want them to do. You can add additional elsif controls when needed.
You have to install this function and the event trigger in each database that needs this behavior. Usually just your development database, for test and production databases you (should) have a complete installation script.
As you can see in the tests, a NULL will still violate a NOT NULL constraint. Only the usage of DEFAULT or the absence of the column in the INSERT will result the usage of your default value. And of course it also works like this for UPDATE statements.

If the column is NOT NULL, it has to have a default value.
Why not adding a: DEFAULT  negative number or zero
PL/pgSQL query:
ALTER TABLE errors ADD COLUMN user_id INT DEFAULT -1;

or
ALTER TABLE errors ADD COLUMN user_id INT DEFAULT 0;

or
ALTER TABLE errors ADD COLUMN user_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1;

Example: db<>fiddle
For details check documentation:
postgresql-16

However, a NOT NULL column doesn't necessarily has to have a DEFAULT constraint. See fiddle.

Not sure what this answer is, but it seems wrong on so many layers... is this the work of some "AI"?
NOT NULL columns do not need a default. Just if they have none and no value (and this is also the meaning of NULL) or NULL is provided, PostgreSQL throws an error (as should every other DB, but sadly not all do).
And what is here about PL/pgSQL? These are just some PostreSQL commands, just normal SQL, no procedural language.
You are also linking to the documentation of PostgreSQL 7.3. Not sure, but it feels like this version is out of support since a century by now.

Finally, this does not even answer the question of assigning default values to types without the need to set a default per column.
Please read the question and your answer before you post it and check if they fit together and if your answer makes sense

@TheImpaler I think the clause just goes into the same spot where you normally specify constraints, but I don't see it being referred to as a constraint - it's just mentioned in the constraint section in the syntax: where column_constraint is:...DEFAULT default_expr... which I'd guess is just to keep things tidy. Generated columns also share that spot.

Are you seriously referencing to PostgreSQL version 7.3? That's EOL since 2008! Why would you use such an outdated manual?

Sorry, PL/pgsql 7.3 docs linking was my mistake... Actually I'm following PL/pgSQL 16, but by mistake I linked that... thank you all to correct me

What has PL/pgSQL to do with this? That's a programming language for PostgreSQL, that has nothing to do with the question nor solution.

I'm a postgres learner, start learning from feb, 2024. So, most of doubts or anything related to postgres, I follow postgres native documentation.  I'm not an expert in postgres.

A NOT NULL column like any column without a declared DEFAULT has a default DEFAULT of NULL.  This where the OP is running into trouble, in the absence of a value being supplied in the INSERT the DEFAULT value of NULL is used which trips the NOT NULL constraint.
